# A C++ Implementation of Hidden Markov Model Dekang Lin install error

Tags: c++, hidden-markov-models

I have download the [A C++ Implementation of Hidden Markov Model](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~lindek/hmm.htm) written by Dekang Lin, but I caught a error when I type `make` in src directory.

**Thanks @Michael, this problem solved**.

In `tables.cpp`, add `#include <cstdlib>`.

In `genseq.cpp` and `trainhmm.cpp`, add `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Error info:

```
g++ -c -o tables.o -g  tables.cpp
tables.cpp: In member function 'bool OneDTable::rand(long unsigned int&)':
tables.cpp:155:24: error: '::rand' has not been declared
tables.cpp:155:34: error: 'RAND_MAX' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [tables.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Does `tables.cpp` include `<cstdlib>`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling your compiler yourself. That project contains a Makefile, so run `make` and better fix what's broken in the Makefile and sources than try to individually build `.o`s yourself. **But:**

Probably that table.cpp is missing the `#include` line where the header would have been included where `OneDTable::rand(..)` would have been declared. Also, missing `::rand` indicates that there are missing standard library includes. This doesn't shine a great light on the integrity of that source code. Maybe, just maybe, as a C++ beginner, you don't want to start off with broken C++ that's 12 years old.

If you're not overly set on pure C++, you can use [gHMM](http://ghmm.org), which is much more mature (and written in C, so works flawlessly in C++, but isn't as much object-oriented). Also, [HMMlib](http://www.cs.au.dk/~asand/?page_id=152) looks pretty nice.